# My program keeps saying that the method cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, resolve

This program should tell me if it can find the file I am naming. Eclipse has no red lines but every time I run it I get this error message and I don't know why. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

```
import java.io.File;

public class StockMarket {
    public StockMarket(String[] args) {
        ReadFiles r = new ReadFiles();
        System.out.println(r.checkIsFile());
    }
}
```

and the second class

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.StringTokenizer; 

public class ReadFiles {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test");
        File file = new File("C:\\stocks\\yahoo.csv");
        int row = 0;
        String[] [] items;
    }

    public boolean checkIsFile() {
        File file= new File("C:\\stocks\\yahoo.csv");
        return file.isFile();
    }
}
```

Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
checkIsFile cannot be resolved or is not a field
    at StockMarket.main(StockMarket.java:6)
```

Comment: Your code indentation is terrible which makes it harder for anyone to read and understand your code. Please fix this.

Comment: This looks like versioning/caching issue. Try a clean build

Comment: Your question seems to be missing some of the code. The exception stack trace says `at StockMarket.main(StockMarket.java:6)`, but the code you've posted doesn't include a `main` method in the `StockMarket` class.

Answer (score 2):

A few things to try.

It looks like your ReadFiles class is not being compiled.

You might try adding an import statement for your ReadFiles class to your main.

Do a clean build.

Also be aware that occasionally Eclipse goes "weird" and you need to do some combination of close it reopen it and/or clean the workspace and/or reboot.  I know you would think with modern software... but still it happens.

Here are a couple of links that may help.

[Keeping Eclipse running clean](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61566.html)

[Restarting Eclipse Clean If You Cannot Run Eclipse From A Command Line (Mac OSX)](http://www.thoughtdelimited.org/thoughts/post.cfm/restarting-eclipse-clean-if-you-cannot-run-eclipse-from-a-command-line-mac-osx)

As an aside, on some prior projects and versions of eclipse I found myself having to do this so frequently that I ended up just setting up eclipse to always launch with the clean option.

Comment: Can  you post a cleaned up version of the code as I don't quite understand what you mean. Sorry, I am very new to programming

Comment: @josh75337 He isn't talking about code changes. He's talking about how some stuff may hve gotten out of sync so your copy of Eclipse is losing track of files.

Comment: yes that is correct there have been times when I have even had to go so far as to track down the actual .class files in the file system and manually delete them from the temp/build directories because ~somehow~ they got marked as read only.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(r.checkIsFile());
```

should be in the static main function, you are going the wrong way for the flow of code...